# Swift 2.2 Optional Type autocorrection

Tags: swift

Swift 2.1 code which worked without any problem:

```
let userDetail  = response["params"]?["users"]
```

I updated to Xcode 7.3 which runs Swift 2.2. And it's start to complain on same above line.
It complains like:

> Value of optional type AnyObject? not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?' ?

When I auto corrected xcode suggestion it is giving me following code as a corrected one:

```
  let userDetail          = response["params"]?!["users"]
```

Here response is of type `AnyObject?`

I dont want to forcefully  unwrap an optional here.

Does anybody know what's the problem here? And what has changed about optionals in Swift 2.2 which is giving me this error.

Comment: What is the type of `userDetail`?

Comment: It is of type Dictionary. I access the values in it like: userDetail?["gender"] as? String

Answer (score 3):

For a dictionary `[K: V]`, the return type of the subscript is `V?`, and thus in your case the return type of `response["params"]` is `AnyObject??` since `V == AnyObject?`. To recover an `AnyObject` to need to unwrap twice:

```
// swift 2.2 only:

//                                  v
let userDetail = response["params"]??["users"]

// note: the type of userDetail is still `AnyObject??`
```

I'm not sure what is changed in Swift 2.2, maybe the check becomes stricter.

---

**Update:** In Swift 3 the type of `userDetail` becomes `Any??` and you can't chain further subscripts. In fact Swift 3's JSONSerialization is [changed to return `Any` instead of `AnyObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520471/jsonserialization-with-swift-3), so you can't even write `response["params"]`. Consider using dedicated JSON packages like [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.2 is more restrictive about key/index subscription of `AnyObject` returned from a dictionary key.

You could use a chained optional binding checking against the expected type,

```
if let userDetail = response["params"] as? [String:AnyObject], users = userDetail["users"] as? Whatever {}
```