# JSONSerialization with Swift 3

Tags: json, swift

I am having a bear of a time understanding simple JSON serialization principles with Swift 3. Can I please get some help with decoding JSON from a website into an array so I can access it as `jsonResult["team1"]["a"]` etc? Here is relevant code:

```
let httprequest = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myurl){ (data, response, error) in

self.label.text = "RESULT"

    if error != nil {

        print(error)

    } else {

        if let urlContent = data {

            do {

                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: 
                    JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)

                print(jsonResult) //this part works fine

                print(jsonResult["team1"])

                } catch {

                    print("JSON Processing Failed")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    httprequest.resume()
```

the incoming JSON is:

```
{
team1 = {
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = red;
};

team2 = {
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = yellow;
};
team3 = {
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = green;
};
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

In Swift 3, the return type of `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:options:)` has become `Any`.

(You can check it in the Quick Help pane of your Xcode, with pointing on `jsonResult`.)

And you cannot call any methods or subscripts for the variable typed as `Any`. You need explicit type conversion to work with `Any`.

```
    if let jsonResult = jsonResult as? [String: Any] {
        print(jsonResult["team1"])
    }
```

And the default Element type of `NSArray`, the default Value type of `NSDictionary` have also become `Any`. (All these things are simply called as "id-as-Any", [SE-0116](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0116-id-as-any.md).)

So, if you want go deeper into you JSON structure, you may need some other explicit type conversion.

```
        if let team1 = jsonResult["team1"] as? [String: Any] {
            print(team1["a"])
            print(team1["b"])
            print(team1["c"])
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. The information from OOPer helped. But, what really helped was reformatting my json:

```
{ "teams": [ { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": "red" }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": "yellow" }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": "green" } ] }
```