# Writing into JSON file iOS Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have JSON file locally in my app. I want to add new element in this file programmatically. Below is my JSON format -

```
{  
   "MENU":{  
      "SUBMENU":[  
         {  
            "name":"name1",
            "link":"link2"
         }
    ]
    }
}
```

I want to add another element in SUBMENU like below -

```
{  
   "MENU":{  
      "SUBMENU":[  
         {  
            "name":"name1",
            "link":"link1"
         },
         {  
            "name":"name2",
            "link":"link2"
         }
    ]
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to do it programatically? Thank!

Comment: Transform in into `[String:Any]` (dictionary), add the info you want, and save it. Note that you can't save into your bundle, you have to  save it elsewhere (with `NSFileManager`, NSDirectoryPath, etc. for instance), and read this one afterwards.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How exactly to add and save into .json flie? And yes the file is not in bundle.

Comment: @RichaSrivastava Could you share your problematically swift code? What are you did?

Comment: Take a look at this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520471/jsonserialization-with-swift-3