# Swift 3 Rest API not working

Tags: json, swift3

Having trouble with Rest API in Swift 3.  Here's my code:

```
func getData()
{
    let urlString = "http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/regions?apikey=QVU3TATgJEdRyojFze6zivdrmiln9XlA"

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default // Session Configuration
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config) // Load configuration into Session
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error!.localizedDescription)

        } else {

            do {
                print("in do block")
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
                {
                    print("if condition is true")
                    //Implement your logic
                    print(json)

                } else
                {
                    print("Error in json serial")
                }

            } catch {

                print("error in JSONSerialization")

            }


        }

    })
    task.resume()
}
```

After execution I can see the following print statements:

in do block
Error in son serial

Cannot figure out what is wrong with JSON Serialization command here.  Expected responses is a JSON array.  Any help would be appreciated. Thx

Comment: Try printing the value of `data` before attempting to serialize

Comment: 'data' is fine.  converted to string and printed it out.  can see my json string.

Comment: Try changing options to `.mutableContainers`, and also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39520853/4656341

Answer (score 0):

Change the 
`if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:[]) as? [String: Any]`

To

```
 if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:[]) as? [Any]
```

beacuse the json you have is "jsonWithArrayRoot" check this for further details.
https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37